# Will UPDATE benefit from INDEX that contains all the UPDATE params?

Tags: sql-server, index, update

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table with a clustered index and two non clustered ones on certain columns.
I have a certain update that is being done quite regularly and updates a numeric(10,2) column (lets call it ColumnA)

```
UPDATE Table1
SET ColumnA = XXX
WHERE ColumnB = YYY
AND ColumnC = ZZZ
AND ColumnD = CCC
AND ColumnE = VVV
```

Will this update benefit from an Index that will contain the WHERE clause columns?

```
CREATE INDEX Table1_ind4 ON Table1(ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ColumnE)
go
```

Thank you

**EDIT:** If I **INCLUDE**d the rest of the Columns in the two non clustered indexes, will it be better?

Comment: Maybe it will, maybe it won't; did you try creating such an index?

Comment: Do the other indexes also include columns B-E? Are the key columns unique (even though the index wasn't declared as such)?

Comment: Thanx Dan. The combination of the Columns is indeed unique. Some of the Columns (lets say ColumnB and ColumnC) are included in the two non clustered indexes (one index per column)

Comment: mustaccio It is a production DB

Comment: So I guess you mean that you don't have a test environment and you don't want to apply the changes to production unless someone on the internet tells you that's OK, right?

Comment: No. I am just wondering. BTW copying Brent's jokes is a bit sad though. Leave the jokes to Brent ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Will this update benefit from an Index that will contain the WHERE clause columns?
>
> . . .
>
> The combination of the Columns is indeed unique

Yes.  Those columns form an alternate key.  And should have a unique index for both performance and to enforce data integrity.

The next questions are whether this should be the clustered index, and whether the current clustered index is necessary?

Comment: Thank you David. Well, it was a design choice to have a seperate column as primary key/clustered index.

Comment: That doesn't mean it was a good design choice, or that it can't be revisited.